# Is there any way to compare Bio-metric data(finger print) captured from one device(Mantra) with the data captured from another device(nitgen)

Tags: .net, biometrics

We have bio metric data(finger print data) of approx 100000 learners with us, which is captured using "Nitgen" device. But now due to some reason, we are changing our vendor to "Mantra". 
I want to know 2 things:

1. Can I use the existing data for the attendance.
2. If I am going to register those fingers again, what precautions I can take to make the new data compatible with all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the fingerprint template algorithm used in both the scanner are same. If so, you can very will reuse the templates on each other. Most probably it will not be the same. If you have maintained the fingerprints in image format. Then you can implement your own Automatic Finger Identification algorithm or you have to use third party services such as

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)